# Making an editable designtime component for Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, pascal, design-time

I've been searching the whole internet for an answer but I cant find one.

What I want to do is to create a component that I, in design time, can add components to, move them around, right click on them to pop up a menu, change their properties, etc etc.

Like, for instance, I drop my component "A" (which is based on `TImage32` from the Graphics32 library), and then I want to be able to drop a component "B" (which is based on `TBitmap32`) in to A, but since B is not inherited from a standard VCL like `TPanel` I dont know how to make a design time component.

Comment: What do you want exactly? 1) A workaround to turn "A" component into some TPanel-like container or 2) To extend "A" component capability to embbed a (collection of ?) "B" component or 3) To write an advanced component editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is the ability to create a parent/child relationship. The parent acts as a container and the child is contained within the bounds of the container. A `TPanel` is a classic example of a container. Any visual component can be a child.

In terms of ancestry the parent must be derived from `TWinControl` and the child must be derived from `TControl`. In practice you seldom derive from these classes directly, rather from one of their descendents. The other factor, if I recall correctly, is that the parent control must include `csAcceptsControls` in its [`ControlStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.ControlStyle).

Now, `TImage32` does indeed derive from `TWinControl` and so it can act as a container. However, I am not sure whether or not `csAcceptsControls` is included in the `ControlStyle` for `TImage32`.

<strike>I'm really not familiar with `TImage32` and don't know whether or not it can act as a parent. I have a suspicion that it is not designed to act as a container. If that is the case then you can add `csAcceptsControls` to the `ControlStyle` in the constructor of your derived class and have the control act as a parent.</strike>

I suspect that if `TImage32` does not include `csAcceptsControls` then this is by design and the image control is not expected to act as a parent.

Apparently `TImage32`, unlike the VCL `TImage`, is indeed capable of acting as a parent to other controls.

As for the other control in your question, `TBitmap32` is not derived from `TControl` and cannot be a child control.

Comment: A is derived from TcustomControl, and could therefore very well act as a container. The problem is that B is not derived from TControl and therefore not suitable for what the OP wants to do.

Comment: hmmm... need to do some research on those things you pointed out.

Comment: @iamjoosy Thanks for that. In fact I suspect that it may be even more complex. I have a feeling that `TImage32` won't accept children.

Comment: however, something like david said.
what I want to do is to have a parent and children inside this parent.
I find it hard to describe what my project is but short in short Ive made a library which allows you to create a parent and have children in it, but its all in runtime, I want to be able to use it in designtime aswell.
however it does not have to run in realtime when used in designtime, I just want te developer to see a draft example of whats going on.

Comment: @david hefferman TImage32 does accept children, you can drop any component inside it.

Comment: Well, in that case the issue is presumably `TBitmap32`.

Comment: hmmm.... so theres no possibility at all to draw something on TImage32 at designtime? at all?

Comment: @xaid Who said anything about drawing something on `TImage32`? And where do mouse events come into it? Your question appears to be about parent/child relationships. I'm very confused now.

Comment: hahaha sorry about that...
OK, I'll give it another shot then.

What I want to do is to create a designtime editor where I can drop my components inside this editor and such. Just the way I drop a button on a form or inside a TPanel etc...

The knowledge I lack is how to recieve mouse events in designtime to my editor, and how to update the editor so it draws its children onto itself.

I dont know maybe I just re-said what I said before but I really dont know how else to say it.

Comment: remember I want my component to update itself in designtime, the runtime part Ive already developed, I want it to partially do what it does in runtime, to do it in designtime.

Comment: That's really a completely different question. You should ask a new question to get help with that. Remember to take your time writing the question. Perhaps include some screenshots. You may need to add them as off-site links but someone with more reputation than you will edit the question to make them appear inline.

Comment: sorry about the confusion...
I'll just copy my comment and make it a new question.
thank you for your time

Comment: Well, try and expand the comment and add some more detail because I think people will still struggle understanding what you are trying to achieve. I still don't really know what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe you'd have an example of what you want to do, but implemented in another software...this would help, by analogy, to get what you are trying to do.

Comment: I made a new question where I asked the question in a video instead
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646834/editable-component-in-designtime